With Project Orion nuclear pulse propulsion, what were the predicted travel times to Mars, Jupiter, and Saturn?
I know it's been canceled for a very long time and involved using literal nuclear shaped charges for propulsion, but I’m still interested in the answer.

@controlgroup mind going a step further and pointing out the parts of the Wikipedia article responsive to the question?  I see a 125 day round trip profile proposed for Mars (which isn't the travel time, or double the travel time, necessarily), a 3-year return from Saturn (also round trip time? unclear) and nothing for Jupiter.

@controlgroup numbers and a link would be lovely, because I've tried to look for the answer and have still come up short.  You getting 1/3 of the answer, not getting the rest, and then telling the asker to look it up is actually just rude.

@controlgroup - if you can spend the effort to write these comments, which aren't very welcoming to new users, you could probably write an answer instead. Please be nice.

According to an Inference article that I found

It would take about a year to travel to Jupiter, two years to Saturn, seven years to Neptune and Pluto

